# QGIS 3.4 - Symbology expression for features that have not been styled by rules

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, rule-based

I have a rule based set of expressions for styling a map according to the contents of the 'Layer' field.  e.g if the Layer starts with a 'C'

`"Layer" ILIKE 'C%'` colours the line red.

Is it possible for me to colour lines which don't fit into any of my pre defined categories ?

i.e I want to have a feature set called `'Other'` into which anything that does not fit my pre-defined rules goes.

I suppose it is theoretically possible to have `CASE/ else/ or /` but this could run into 100s of lines of code.

Is there a way of saying - 'if a feature in the `'Layer'` field equals none of the above, then style it like this....?

That is the best way I can think of explaining it.

Comment: Just add a rule with the filter expression `ELSE`. In the QGIS 3.10, this is an option in the editing rule dialog `ELSE`. Literally, if any of the other rule is true / met, then do this `ELSE` rule.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use QGIS 3.10 as I have encountered an issue with the OSM maps and projections.  3.4 does not seem to have else in it's expressions.

Comment: Yes, there is no `ELSE` in the expression but just type `ELSE` as expression, even if it's invalid, it'll work even in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: Great! worked perfectly - thank you